# How do I copy a window to the clipboard?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

What's the convenient way of copying, say, the debug window to the clipboard so I can then paste it on, say, some popular programming QA site ;)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pharo a convenient way is to bring the halos and click in the "Menu Halo" (red icon), then export -> PNG, JPEG, etc.

To bring the halos (in Windows) hold the Alt+Shift+Click. If halos appear in a morph inside a window, then click again until you reach the outer window.